# How to get the URL to a specific record page in render function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, jquery, datatable

I am trying to generate the dynamic URL to redirect to record but it appends the id to the current page.

For example, I am getting--> 
https://nishant-aishwarya-1234-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/0062w000003ar1dAAA/view

What I want--> 
https://nishant-aishwarya-1234-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0062w000003ar1dAAA/view

This is the code to my render function-->

```
 if(columnNames[i]=='name'){
            columns.push({data: columnNames[i], 
            title: columnNames[i],
            render: function(data, type, row, meta){
            data = '<a href=' + row['id'] + '/view'+'>' + data + '</a>';
            return data;
            }

        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me,

```
 data = '<a href="/lightning/r/Opportunity/' + row['id'] + '/view" target = _blank>' + data + '</a>';
  return data;
```